# Computer waking up from sleep after being unplugged for hours

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Yesterday I (thought I) turned my computer off, but I wasn't really sure if I missed the button and accidentally clicked sleep. I unplugged the power cord, just one of my weird habits. This morning I woke up after 9 hours of sleep turned on my computer and went downstairs for breakfast. However before I could leave the room I got a notification on my phone about Whatsapp Web being active. So I turned around and saw my computer was already at the login screen. I enter my password and my browser and other programs that I didn't bother to close were still there.

How is it possible that this happened?

Answer (score 0):

Emmm…interesting.

This is my guess:

Your computer actually is not close!

Your click shutdown/sleep, screen became blue screen and appears shutting down…

You was turning around and leaving.

After you went downstairs, shutdown process was broken off because your some programs are running and cannot be closed.

Blue screen recovered to desktop and your programs still running.

In order to save power(you have unplugged the power cord) system turn off the display and lock itself(sleep)

The next day, you are facing the current scenario.

Answer (score 0):

What you have as "sleep" on modern computers is actually a "hybrid sleep".  It is a full hibernation of the system followed by suspending the system to RAM.

What this means is that should the power be removed while the system is in sleep then it just boots the system back to where it was using the hibernation file.  It is effectively a hard drive back up for the sleep function.

[What is Hybrid Sleep?](https://www.maketecheasier.com/hybrid-sleep-on-windows/)